# Widget not handling click event

Tags: java, android, gridview, widget

i already checked all the other already solved question but no one fixed my issue. If anyone could help me it would be wonderful. Thanks in advance.

I am using a GridView with 1 column.
I want to open the MainActivity.class on the GridView or on an item click.
Currently it is not working and i do not understand the reason.
This is my widget provider class:

```
public class BakingWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
final String myClickEvent = "click";
void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId) {

    RemoteViews remoteViews = getRecipeGridRemoteView(context);

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
}

public RemoteViews getRecipeGridRemoteView(Context context) {
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.baking_widget_provider);

    Intent gridIntent = new Intent(context, GridWidgetService.class);
    views.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.grid, gridIntent);

    Intent appIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, appIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    views.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.ingredient_widget_layout, appIntent);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ingredient_widget_layout, getPendingSelfIntent(context, myClickEvent));


    return views;
}

 protected PendingIntent getPendingSelfIntent(Context context, String action) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, getClass());
    intent.setAction(action);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
@Override
public void onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                      int appWidgetId, Bundle newOptions) {
    updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
    super.onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId, newOptions);
}

@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
}

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context) {
}


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    if (intent != null) {
        if ("android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE".equals(intent.getAction())) {
            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
            int[] appwidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(
                    new ComponentName(context, getClass())
            );
            appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appwidgetIds, R.id.grid);
            onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appwidgetIds);
        }
    } else if (myClickEvent.equals(intent.getAction())){
        Toast.makeText(context, "msg msgasdasd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}}
```

My gridview adapter class here:

```
public class GridWidgetService extends RemoteViewsService {

@Override
public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) {
    return new GridRemoteViewsFactory(this.getApplicationContext(), intent);
}

public class GridRemoteViewsFactory implements RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory {


    ArrayList<Ingredient> ingredientsListGrid;
    Food[] foodList;
    String latestHeader;
    final String be = "bodyItem";
    Context mContext;

    public GridRemoteViewsFactory(Context mContext, Intent intent) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        //foodList = getFoods();
        ingredientsListGrid = getIngredients();
        Log.wtf("INGREDIENTS SIZE", String.valueOf(ingredientsListGrid.size()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataSetChanged() {
        // foodList = getFoods();
        ingredientsListGrid = getIngredients();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return (ingredientsListGrid != null) ? ingredientsListGrid.size() : 0;
    }

    private ArrayList<Ingredient> getIngredients() {

        Cursor ingredientCursor = mContext.getContentResolver()
                .query(ItemsContract.IngredientEntry.CONTENT_URI_INGREDIENT_TABLE,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null);

        ArrayList<Ingredient> ingredients = new ArrayList<>();
        if (ingredientCursor != null) {
            while (ingredientCursor.moveToNext()) {
                Ingredient ingredient = getIngredientFromCursor(ingredientCursor);
                ingredients.add(ingredient);
            }
            ingredientCursor.close();
        }


        return ingredients;
    }

    private Food[] getFoods() {
        Uri baseIngredientUri = ItemsContract
                .FoodEntry
                .CONTENT_URI_FOOD_TABLE.buildUpon().build();

        String ingredientUriString = baseIngredientUri.toString();
        Uri ingredientUri = Uri.parse(ingredientUriString);

        Cursor ingredientCursor = mContext.getContentResolver()
                .query(ingredientUri,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null);

        Food[] foods = new Food[ingredientCursor.getCount()];
        if (ingredientCursor != null) {
            while (ingredientCursor.moveToNext()) {
                Food food = getFoodFromCursor(ingredientCursor);
                foods[ingredientCursor.getPosition()] = (food);
            }
            ingredientCursor.close();
        }
        return foods;
    }

    private Food getFoodByName(String name) {
        return null;
    }


    private Ingredient getIngredientFromCursor(Cursor ingredientCursor) {
        Ingredient ingredient = new Ingredient();

        ingredient.setIngredient(ingredientCursor.getString(ingredientCursor
                .getColumnIndex(ItemsContract.IngredientEntry.COLUMN_INGREDIENT_NAME)));
        ingredient.setMeasure(ingredientCursor.getString(ingredientCursor
                .getColumnIndex(ItemsContract.IngredientEntry.COLUMN_INGREDIENT_MEASURE)));
        ingredient.setQuantity(ingredientCursor.getDouble(ingredientCursor
                .getColumnIndex(ItemsContract.IngredientEntry.COLUMN_INGREDIENT_QUANTITY)));

        String name = ingredientCursor.getString(ingredientCursor
                .getColumnIndex(ItemsContract.IngredientEntry.COLUMNS_FOOD_NAME)).replace("_", " ");

        if (ingredientCursor.getPosition() == 0 || !name.equals(latestHeader) || latestHeader == null) { // a sort of Section Header to divide foods ingredients
            ingredient.setFoodName(name);
            latestHeader = name;
        } else {
            ingredient.setFoodName(be + name);
        }

        return ingredient;
    }

    private Food getFoodFromCursor(Cursor foodCursor) {
        Food food = new Food();
        food.setServings(foodCursor.getInt(foodCursor
                .getColumnIndex(ItemsContract.FoodEntry.COLUMN_FOOD_SERVINGS)));
        food.setName(foodCursor.getString(foodCursor
                .getColumnIndex(ItemsContract.FoodEntry.COLUMN_FOOD_NAME)).replace("_", " "));
        return food;
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getViewAt(int i) {

        if (ingredientsListGrid.size() == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_ingredient_item_layout);
        //  String title = ingredientsListGrid.get(i).getIngredient();
        //  String measure = ingredientsListGrid.get(i).getMeasure();
        //  Double quantity = ingredientsListGrid.get(i).getQuantity();
        Ingredient ingredient = ingredientsListGrid.get(i);
        if (ingredient.getFoodName() != null && !ingredient.getFoodName().contains(be)) {
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.food_name, ingredient.getFoodName());
            remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.food_name, View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.food_name, View.GONE);
        }

        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.ingredient_name, ingredientsListGrid.get(i).getIngredient());
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.ingredient_quantity, ingredient.getQuantity() + " " + ingredient.getMeasure());
        String foodName = ingredient.getFoodName();


        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putString("foodNmae", foodName);
        Intent fillInIntent = new Intent();
        fillInIntent.putExtras(extras);
        remoteViews.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.ingredient_widget_layout, fillInIntent);

        return remoteViews;
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getLoadingView() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }
}}
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: In the `AppWidgetProvider`, you should be calling `setPendingIntentTemplate()` for the `GridView`, with the `PendingIntent` that's "filled in" with the `Intent` you call `setOnClickFillInIntent()` with in the `RemoteViewsService`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this fixed my problem, if you write it as answer i'll mark it as solution!

Comment: Actually, it's a common oversight that's been addressed here before, so I'll just mark this as a duplicate. Thanks, though. I appreciate the offer. Glad you got it working. Cheers!